# Newly compiled React app acting as expecting, subsequent runs exhibiting unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a visualizer for popular sorting algorithms using React. The program randomly generates an array of integer values which it represents as bars on the screen. The taller the bar, the higher the number. The bars are in random order. The visualizer animates the sorting so that the viewer sees step-by-step how the algorithm works, until all bars are sorted from shortest to tallest. My problem arises with Quick Sort. Sometimes, the program executes properly and shows the bars correctly sorted when the algorithm terminates. Other times, it does not. Sometimes there is one bar out of place, sometimes two or three or four. I checked my array in state, and it appears to be sorted, leading me to believe that this is an animation issue. The behavior (correct/incorrect display of the array) seems to be random. The only consistency I find is that when I make changes to the program in the IDE, then recompile, the first run always succeeds (8 for 8 so far on arrays that consistently display 4-6 bars incorrectly after the first run). What is happening here? Is there something going on with memory? Here is the function that handles animations. I will attach the sorting function and the verification function if it helps.

```
export const quickSortAnimations = animations => {
  const arrayBars = document.getElementsByClassName('array-bar');

  for(let i=0; i < animations.length; ++i){
    const {leftIdx, rightIdx, pivot, swap} = animations[i];
    const leftBarStyle = arrayBars[leftIdx].style;
    const rightBarStyle = arrayBars[rightIdx].style;
    const pivotBarStyle = arrayBars[pivot].style;
    setTimeout(() => {
      pivotBarStyle.backgroundColor = 'purple';
      leftBarStyle.backgroundColor = 'red';
      setTimeout(() => {
        leftBarStyle.backgroundColor = 'turquoise';
        if (swap){
          if(rightIdx === pivot) rightBarStyle.backgroundColor = 'turquoise';
          const tmpHeight = leftBarStyle.height;
          leftBarStyle.height = rightBarStyle.height;
          rightBarStyle.height = tmpHeight;
        }
      }, 2);
    }, i * 3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing the random number generator with a seed to identify a specific example on which your app fails?

Comment: I am logging the broken array before and after the sort to the console. I also log any difference between a value at a given index of the array and the height of the corresponding bar in the DOM. The weird thing is that the incorrect bars represent values that are not in the original array, nor are they in the sorted array. I find this odd because the only operation that happens among bars is the reassigning of their heights (no arithmetic).

Comment: I believe your nested `setTimeout` is causing the problem. For e.g.: outer "timeout" for 20th elemtent will execute after 60ms, inner after 62ms, while for 21st it will be 63ms and 65ms. Any difference in order will cause different result.

What is more `setTimeout` callbacks may be throttled to ≥ 4ms, check Notes section of documentation for setTimeout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Notes

Comment: This is interesting. I increased the timeouts to 10 and 20 seconds (meaning the 20th element will execute after 400ms, inner after 410ms, while the 21st at 420ms and 430ms) to prevent any overlapping behavior. I still see the unexpected behavior after a couple sorts. I'll try to write a test that compares many sets of supposedly sorted bars against their corresponding sorted arrays to see if I can find any sort of partner among the bars that are out of place. The strangest thing is that the out-of-place bars don't seem to represent numbers in either the starting or ending array...